# Can't install or uninstall The Surge 2 in Xbox Game Pass

Tags: xbox-game-pass, the-surge-2

I made a video of the problem:

Basically The Surge 2 is in my games list, but it hasn't installed. It looks like it has (the icon is full colour), but it hasn't. I can't install it, and I can't remove it from my game list by uninstalling it. It's just stuck there.

Doe anyone know what I can do here? I want to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Installed the latest Windows Updates, and when the computer restarted (I had restarted previously), The Surge 2 was no longer in my game list and it's now installing. I doubt this will help anyone but WU is what fixed it for me ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and uninstall it through the list of installed apps in your Windows 10 settings window? You might be able to uninstall it there.

You can get to that window by clicking the text bubble in the lower-right corner of your screen, clicking "all settings", then clicking on "Apps" in the list that appears. You can then search for The Surge 2 and hopefully uninstall it.

Comment: But he said the game is not installed, how is this going to help matters? You might as well post this as a comment.

Comment: Yea the game isn't actually installed so it doesn't appear in that list. It's very strange.